# Fastest way to create Rails "smoke and mirrors" integration tests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, integration-testing

I want to quickly add tests for every route that tests if the page blows up or not. That's it. What would be the quickest way to do this?

Right now in my head I'm thinking of rspec and trying to hit every page with an appropriate action (get/post,etc).

But that seems pretty laborious, is there a quicker solution?

Comment: FYI: "smoke and mirrors" means fake, whereas "smoke test" means a quick is-it-working test, which is what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

I was just playing in the Rails console and I came up with this:

```
YourAppName::Application.routes.routes.map { |r| [r.verb, r.path] }
```

That will give you all the verbs and paths defined in your routes. You can iterate over all the paths and try making a request for each one.

Comment: What does that give you over `rake routes`?

Comment: @DFischer wants to write a unit test which will make a request for each route, and see if any of them throw an exception. This code would save him from parsing the output of `rake routes`.